# Logging progress of loop of promises in HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

With the code below I'm trying to document the progress of a series of loops.

However, as you will see, the progress is not documented smoothly in the DOM. Lots of percentage increments are being skipped.

How can I fix that ?

```
;(async () => {
  let width = document.getElementById('width')
  let numOfImages = 8
  let images = Array.from(Array(numOfImages).keys())
  let pixelsPerImage = 3600
  let totalPixels = numOfImages * pixelsPerImage
  let currentLoop = 0

  for (let img of images) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      // this setTimeout is actually an image.onload callback
      setTimeout(() => {
        let i = 0
        while (i < pixelsPerImage) {
          ;(function(cloop) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
              let prcnt = ((100/totalPixels) * cloop).toFixed(2)
              width.innerHTML = prcnt + '%'
              width.style.width = prcnt + '%'
            })
          })(++currentLoop)
          i++
        }
        resolve()
      }, 5000)
    })
  }

  await Promise.all(promises)
})()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koyfa6pm/1/

Comment: What does "However, as you will see, the progress is not documented correctly in the DOM." mean?  Progress from what?  Please describe exactly what you expect to see and what you do see?  `console.log()` when you send a firehose of data at it is NOT necessarily realtime.  It can get behind.  Meanwhile, the DOM just replaces the previous value with the new value and moves on.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the solution. If the answers did not answer your question, add your own answer, including the code of the solution (not just a link to a jsfiddle).

Comment: What is the `while (i < innerLoops)` supposed to achieve? That just schedules multiple `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks at once, which naturally will be run together all for the same animation frame.

Comment: "What is the while (i < innerLoops) supposed to achieve?" - Going through every pixel of an image. It's a representation of the real scenario  in simpler terms. I now have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It slows down the overall progress, as I'm now waiting for the HTML updates to finish before moving on to the next loop but the progress shown in the HTML is now accurate and smooth. It's a trade off.

```js
;(async () => {
  let width = document.getElementById('width')
  let topLoops = 8
  let innerLoops = 3600
  let totalLoops = topLoops * innerLoops
  let currentLoop = 0
  let images = Array.from(Array(topLoops).keys())

  for (let img of images) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      // this setTimeout is actually an image.onload callback
      setTimeout(async() => {
        let i = 0
        while (i < innerLoops) {
          currentLoop++
          await new Promise((resolve) => {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
              let prcnt = ((100/totalLoops) * currentLoop).toFixed(2)
              width.innerHTML = prcnt + '%'
              width.style.width = prcnt + '%'
              resolve()
            })
          })
          i++
        }
        resolve()
      }, 5000)
    })
  }

  await Promise.all(promises)
})()
```

```css
#width {
  float:left;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="width"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are trying to run 8 promises in parallel but they run one after the other.

It goes like this:
8 promises are created, one after the other. each promise registers a setTimeout for 5000ms.

Once the 5000ms are over there will be 8 callbacks waiting, the runtime will call them one after the other (JavaScript is single threaded).

The first promise will do a 3600 loop, and will write to the `console.log` 3600 times. Then the next promise callback will be called by the runtime, and the next 3600 loop will do the same... till all 8 loops are over.

You see many `console.log` because you do that 3600*8 times... you don't see the DOM changes because the browser will render only after the execution is complete.

In order to see dom changes, you will have to "release" the execution of your code, you can do that with `setTimeout(..., 0)` to get the next immediate render. or even better use `requestAnimationFrame`

You would want to do the minimum every frame to let the browser render it fast. avoid huge loops, slow code.

Next thing you will probably encounter is that the progress speed changes according to your CPU, if you want to be same no matter the CPU power, you would want to start taking time into consideration, which a totally different subject :-)

Comment: The 3600*8 console.logs are expected and I'm fine with that. I want to fix the inconsistency in regards to the DOM changes. I want the DOM changes to also follow the same speed/progress as the console.logs (more or less).

Comment: "you don't see the DOM changes because the browser will render only after the execution is complete" so I guess this is my problem. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: So you mean I need to wrap the 3 lines changing the DOM into a `setTimeout(.., 0)` ?

Comment: It will work, but I wouldn't go this path... better use `requestAnimationFrame` to progress on every frame. Promises are not relevant to what you want.

Comment: Or maybe you do want to do something with Promises progress but did not really asked that in your question?

Comment: the `new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(() => { ... resolve() }) })` in my example stands for an asynchronous image load. I omitted it for simplicity. The number of loops is the actual one and I can't decrease it unfortunately. I will try using `requestAnimationFrame` and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Loading images asynchronously sound correct, but a huge loop that updates the DOM will not work, so yea try `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle and the OP. Unfortunately, the progress is still not documented smoothly. I would be fine missing some increments, but here it's quite a few and it looks rather "rough" to the eye. But I don't think we can do any better. It's probably due to my machine's capabilities.

Comment: I fixed it! https://jsfiddle.net/or54vL91/ :)